# Usage of output stream buffer in context to std::cout and std::endl

Tags: c++, output-buffering

I am trying to understand how the output stream buffer works. I didn't find anything that explains the whole process of writing on a standard output in context of `std::cout`. From what I understand, `std::cout` doesn't actually prints on the standard output, rather it writes the content to output stream buffer of the terminal emulator. When the buffer is full, the terminal emulator deletes the contents of the buffer and writes it to the terminal display(standard output). According to me, this is what happens when a `flush` operation is performed by the terminal emulator.

In the case of `std::endl`, an explicit request is made to the terminal emulator to flush the contents of the buffer right away which causes a performance drop. This drop is caused due to the time taken by our program to create a `flush` request to the terminal emulator and waiting for the contents of the buffer to be printed on the terminal display before proceeding to the next line of code. Without `std::endl`, `std::cout` doesn't care about having the contents printed right away. It leaves the responsibility of printing to the terminal emulator(by writing the content into the output stream buffer of the terminal emulator). I have a few doubts:

(1) Is my understanding of how terminal emulators display text requested by `std::cout`, accurate?

(2) Is the `flush` request made to the OS or the terminal emulator?

(3) If we increase the output stream buffer size of the terminal emulator, will there be an increase in the performance of the program complemented by a noticeable delay in printing the contents on the display?

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. Writing a character to a stream will put it in an internal buffer first. When the buffer is flushed it will be written in an OS-dependent way to the operating system. The operating system might then have one or more levels of buffers between your program and the terminal. I also recommend e.g. [this C++ I/O library reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) for more details about how it all fits together on the C++ side.

Comment: Plus, the C++ `std::cout` is tied to the `stdout`, so one may decide to break synchronization with `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false); `.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll read the page that you have provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your understanding is not correct. "Terminal emulators" are not involved, at least not directly.

The output buffer lives within the stream object itself (`std::cout` in this case). There are three possible ways this buffer is used, depending on the buffering policy of the stream:

- Block buffered: Output is stored in the buffer first. When the buffer is full, it is "flushed", i.e. its contents are written to the underlying (OS specific) output channel and the buffer is emptied.
- Line buffered: Works like block buffered, but the buffer is also flushed whenever a newline (`'\n'`) is written to it.
- Unbuffered: The output buffer is not used. All output is written immediately.

When you open a file, the stream starts out being block buffered. `std::cerr` is unbuffered. `std::cout` is line buffered if output goes to a terminal and block buffered otherwise.

`std::flush` flushes the output buffer immediately (if there is any).

As for how data is actually written, the details depend on your operating system. On unix systems, there is a system call called `write` (a "system call" is a request to the operating system to do something). System calls are typically slower than normal function calls; the output buffer is a performance optimization because you don't want to call `write` for every single character of output. Collecting output internally until you have a bigger batch of text to write means fewer calls to `write`, which means better overall performance.

As for your specific questions:

1. No, terminal emulators are not relevant.
2. The OS.
3. The buffer is in the stream object, not the terminal emulator. Increasing the buffer size stops giving you any performance benefits after some point. Your program will usually spend most of its time calculating results and doing things other than writing text to `std::cout`.

Comment: I have a question regarding your explaination. By default, `std::cout` is unbuffered and uses `stdout`'s stream buffer. In your explaination about buffering policy based on output channel, are you talking about  `std::cout`'s stream buffer or `stdout`'s?

Comment: @gtmshrm Ah. My explanation doesn't distinguish between `std::cout` and `stdout`. When you see `std::cout` above, read it as "`std::cout` + `stdout`"; the point being that there is a buffer inside your program.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it! Makes much more sense to think `std::cout` and `stdio` as one unless `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);` is set